# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato de "última fecha de modificación" de un fichero o directorio?

Tags: c, linux, date, formato

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo cambiar el formato de "ultima fecha de modificación" de un directorio o fichero.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
char *getTime(time_t t){ (Obtener la ultima fecha de modificación)
   struct dirent *direntp;
   DIR *dir = opendir(".");
   struct stat c;
   while ((direntp = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
       if ((strcmp(direntp -> d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(direntp -> d_name, "..") == 0))
           continue;
       if (lstat(direntp ->d_name, &c) == 0)
           (direntp -> d_name);
       return ctime(&c.st_mtime);
   }
}

void do_Info(char *nom){
    struct stat s;
    char *user, *grupo,*tiempo;

    if (lstat(nom,&s)==-1){
        printf("Imposible acceder a %s:%s\n",nom,strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    user = getUser(s.st_uid);
    grupo = getGroup(s.st_gid);
    tiempo = getTime(s.st_mtime);

    printf("%s %s %s %s\n", user, grupo, tiempo, nom);
}
```

Al usar ese código la ultima fecha de modificacion me sale de la siguiente manera:

```
  Thu Oct 12 17:42:08 2017
```

Ademas de el nombre de usuario, grupo etc.

pero quiero que me salga del siguiente formato:

```
 Oct 12 17:42
```

Resumiendo, que cuando use ejecute el programa, la informacion del fichero o directorio me salga con la fecha asi, como en el comando es linux ls -li:

```
15888887 -rw-r--r-- 1 antonio antonio 2713 Oct 12 17:42 p1.c
```

Un saludo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe una función llamada [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) que permite formatear una fecha a tu gusto... el problema es que no trabaja con `time_t` sino con `tm`, así que antes tienes que convertir de una estructura de fecha a otra, y para esta última tarea podemos usar [`gmtime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/).

```
char *getTime(time_t t){
  static char buffer[50]; // Importante que sea static para no perder la variable

  // ...

  struct tm * stm = gmtime(&c.st_mtime);

  strftime(buffer,50,"%a %d %H:%M",stm);

  return buffer;
}
```

Por cierto... fíjate que no estás haciendo uso de la variable `t` que recibes como parámetro.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono 