# ¿Por qué no me cambia la ultima fecha de modificación de un archivo o directorio?

Tags: c, linux, archivo, date

Me gustaría saber por que cuando ejecuto mi código siempre me sale la misma fecha de la ultima modificación para todos los archivos y directorios.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
char *getTime(time_t t){
    DIR *dir = opendir(".");
    struct dirent *direntp;
    static char buffer[50];
    struct stat c;
    struct tm *stm;
    while ((direntp = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        if ((strcmp(direntp -> d_name, ".") != 0) && (strcmp(direntp -> d_name, "..") != 0))
            continue;
        if (lstat(direntp ->d_name, &c) == 0)
            (direntp -> d_name);
        stm = localtime(&c.st_mtime)
        strftime(buffer, 50, "%b %d %H:%M", stm);
        return buffer;                  
    }       
}

void do_Info(char *nom){
    struct stat s;
    char *user, *grupo, *permisos, *tiempo;

    if (lstat(nom,&s)==-1){
        printf("Imposible acceder a %s:%s\n",nom,strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    user = getUser(s.st_uid);
    grupo = getGroup(s.st_gid);
    permisos=getPermisos(s.st_mode);
    tiempo = getTime(s.st_mtime);

    printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", permisos,user, grupo, tiempo, nom);

}
```

La finalidad del programa es hacer lo mismo que el comando en linux: ls-li

Un saludo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te [comenté](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109091/c%C3%B3mo-cambiar-el-formato-de-%C3%BAltima-fecha-de-modificaci%C3%B3n-de-un-fichero-o-direc) en la respuesta a tu pregunta anterior, la función `getTime` recibe un argumento, `t`... pero **no lo usa**

En su lugar abre el directorio de trabajo e itera por su contenido... peeeeero al llegar al primer fichero (o directorio) retorna el valor de su fecha... luego la fecha retornada será la misma siempre **que no cambie el directorio de trabajo**

¿Solución? Limpiar la función (y si de paso hacemos caso de los detalles que nos comentan en las respuestas mejor que mejor)

```
char *getTime(time_t t){
    static char buffer[50];

    struct tm *stm = localtime(&t)
    strftime(buffer, 50, "%b %d %H:%M", stm);
    return buffer;                  
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, y disculpa las molestias.

Comment: @GilbertHammer no es molestia. Y aunque parezca lo contrario no intento ser brusco. Simplemente intento que entiendas que si te damos algún consejo que se sale un poco de la pregunta inicial suele tener alguna motivación concreta y es de agradecer que, al menos, lo leas y le dediques unos minutos para saber si el comentario es util o no.